# Добавить функцию бана в Telegram бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Как добавить функцию бана юзера по `id`  в Telegram бота?

Т.е чтобы я мог ввести `/ban userid` и этот юзер больше не мог писать боту.

Answer (score 1):

Пользователь в любом случае сможет писать боту, а вот отвечать ему или нет уже решать нам.

Есть 2 способа это сделать, первый с помощью декоратора, который будет проверять не забанен ли наш юзер:

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from functools import wraps

bot = TeleBot('<token>')
banned_users = []


def is_not_banned(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(message):
        if message.from_user.id not in banned_users:
            return func(message)
    return decorator


@bot.message_handler(commands=['ban'])
def ban_user(message):
    message_args = message.text.split()
    if len(message_args) == 2:
        banned_users.append(int(message_args[1]))
        bot.reply_to(message, text='OK')
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, text='Wrong format')


@bot.message_handler()
@is_not_banned
def foo(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, text='Hey!')
```

Как это работает:

- Бот получает апдейт и вызывает наш хендлер.
- Вместо оригинально хендлера, у нас уже функция `decorator` которая замкнула в себе оригинальный хендлер.
- Когда бот её вызывает, она проверяет не забанен ли наш юзер, если нет -- вызывает оригинальный хендлер, в противном случае ничего не делает.

У этого способа есть свой недостаток, мы обрабатываем апдейты забаненных юзеров.

Этого можно избежать переопределив метод `get_updates`:

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot import apihelper
from telebot import types


class MyTeleBot(TeleBot):
    def get_updates(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, *args, **kwargs)
        ret = []
        for ju in json_updates:
            if ju['message']['from']['id'] in banned_users:
                self.last_update_id = ju['update_id']
            else:
                ret.append(types.Update.de_json(ju))
        return ret
```

Теперь создаём экземпляр нашего класса:

```
bot = MyTeleBot('<token>')
```

Далее можем писать наши хендлеры без каких либо декораторов, функция `ban_user` осталась без изменений.

Ну и не забываем запустить поллинг:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Как это работает:

- У нас есть следующая цепочка вызовов при поллинге

  - `infinity_polling > polling > __threaded_polling > __retrieve_updates > get_updates > process_new_updates`
- Перед вызовом `process_new_updates` мы "отсекаем" все ненужные апдейты, тем самым наш хендлер даже не отрабатывает.

#### Как мы "отсекаем" апдейты?

Вы наверняка заметили в нашем классе такую проверку:

```
if ju['message']['from']['id'] in banned_users:
    self.last_update_id = ju['update_id']
```

Дело в том, что если не делать `self.last_update_id = ju['update_id']`, топ наш бот зациклиться на последнем апдейте который мы и хотим пропустить.

Собственно это и делает `process_new_updates`:

```
if update.update_id > self.last_update_id:
    self.last_update_id = update.update_id
```

Вместо массива `banned_users` желательно взять базу данных.

Comment: А как быть во втором примере, если бот использует и сalldata? (inline)